# Possible to change uri in url through mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change a url directed to my site to a different url where a page is located.

i.e. for url http://domain.com/user/file.txt to http://domain.com/login/file.txt - the only thing I want to change between urls is /user/ to /login/.  I've heard this can be accomplished through mod rewrite and .htaccess without having an external redirect.  In essence I want to change the substring of the first to the substring of the last and have the last show even though the first url was used to access.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any .htaccess code?

Comment: I've tried to google for something but was unsuccesful

Comment: Please explain "In essence I want to change the substring of the first to the substring of the last and have the last show even though the first url was used to access."

Comment: If I use the first url to access the site, I want to change the substring /user/ to /login/ in .htaccess

Comment: I just answered a similar question, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698825/1741542

Answer (score 0):

Try the below .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://domain.com/user/file.txt$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.com/login/file.txt$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How is HOST gonna match the full URL?