# How can i create better urls using .htacces modrewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

This are my urls right nowm for my products

http://www.example.com/product.php?product=32723

I want to achieve this

http://www.example.com/product/32723-brand-model-productname

I have been modifying my .htaccess but really with no clue on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must match your URL with a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pattern and rewrite it to the target URL

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(\d+)- /product.php?product=$1
```

This pattern matches any URL starting with `/product/` and captures the following digits `(\d+)` followed by a dash `-`. The substitution URL will be `/product.php?product=` with the captured digits `$1` appended.

To capture some part of the match, you enclose it in parenthesis `(...)`. Read more on regular expressions used in mod_rewrite at [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction - Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: I was able to achieve it using this
RewriteRule ^repuesto/([^/.]+)-?$ product.php?product=$1 [L]
but now the page links and images are distorded, im figuring out why. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is so common I just put up the whole answer with code here:

http://www.prescia.net/bb/coding/5-141018-simple_friendly-url